# facebook redirect entering an endless loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using v 5 RC and the CSMvc3FacebookApp.sln sample.

When I launch the site locally (using IIS Express as WebServer) by browsing to:
http://apps.facebook.com/myTestApp
HomeController/Index View shows up properly. This means that the facebook settings are correct.

However when I hit the 'About' link (this is where the facebook calls are made) I see an endless loop occur between:

http://apps.facebook.com/santiagoit/Home/About 
http://localhost:16874/facebookredirect.axd?code=

If the user is not logged in to facebook. Hitting the 'About' link brings up the facebook login page, endless redirect loop happens after user signs in to facebook.

I tested other sample projects and they behave the same.
I tested with another facebook test app and same results.

I had done a project with the older facebook developer toolkit, but I am new to this SDK.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at the latest docs on the authentication in facebook. They have discontinued the previous protocol for authentication. Now they use straight OAuth2.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast!
Indeed, my app settings had 'OAuth 2.0 for Canvas' disabled.